# Can Facebook SDK for Android Perform auto-delete Operation on User's wall-posts?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have read copious posts regarding Facebook Android API. However unable to figure out whether Facebook SDK are able to delete any user's wall-post automatically without user consent?

Can anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

It is not allowed as stated in the Facebook Platform Policy, If a user grants you a publishing permission, you must still obtain consent from the user before taking any action on the user's behalf. See [here](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/) for more info.

Comment: Got it. One more thing can we read user's wall post messages (with permissions)?

Comment: If you mean read them in order to display them to the user then yes, is that what you meant?